# Calculating powers modulo n

Tags: r, modulus

Is there in R a function allowing to fast calculate powers modulo n ? For example, suppose I want to calculate :

(10 378)^8743 (mod 10403)

I know it's possible to use successives powers of 2 by writing :
8743 = 8192 + 512 + 32 + 4 + 2 + 1

But is something already implemented ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `modpower` function in the [numbers](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=numbers) package is what you want.